# Public accessors

Tags: c#, class

I have the following accessor in `Glass` class:

```
public bool isGlassEnabled{
    get {
         if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) {
             DwmIsCompositionEnabled( ref en );
             if (en > 0) {
                return true;
             } else { return false; }
         } else { return false; }
    }
}
```

(I am not sure if the code is working, but that is not what I am interested in)

Now we are located in `MainClass`. Is there any possibility to access `isGlassEnabled` like this:

```
bool myBool = **without new** Glass.isGlassEnabled;
```

Comment: It's kind of difficult to not be interested in your getter code when there are so many if-xyz-return-true-else-return-false structures in there.

Comment: Is `en` a nonstatic member? If so `static` won't (well shouldn't) compile like some of the answers suggest.

Comment: @Lews Therin: I'm wondering why the OP didn't just make it a local variable instead. There's no reason to keep it around as a field.

Comment: Baffled as well, I hope he clarifies the question (or static works for him).

Answer (score 3):

To make this work

```
bool myBool = **without new** Glass.isGlassEnabled;
```

you just need a `static` property:

```
public static bool isGlassEnabled{
    get { ... }
}
```

And then `bool myBool = Glass.isGlassEnabled;` will simply compile.

Everything you (might) need in the getter is static as well so no problem there.

Edit:

as noted by others, your code contains a variable `en` that should be either local or static.
Together with some else-branch folding:

```
public static bool isGlassEnabled
{
    get 
    {
         if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) 
         {
             Int32 en;   // or whatever type exactly needed
             DwmIsCompositionEnabled( ref en );
             if (en > 0) 
                return true;                
         }
         return false; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, you should mark property as **static**.

```
public static bool isGlassEnabled
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the *static* modifier

```
public static bool isGlassEnabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Use static properties:

```
public static bool isGlassEnabled{
    get {
        TypeTheTypeOfEnVariableHere en;
        if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) {
             DwmIsCompositionEnabled( ref en );
            if (en > 0) {
               return true;
            } else { return false; }
        } else { return false; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Mmn.. not sure that will compile. I think `en` is a non static member.